# Difference between succession of parameters on filtering

Tags: angularjs

I am absolutely new in ***angularjs framework***, and learning filtering now. I write a simple filtering for currency.

My codes are as follow:

```
{{99.9 | currency | number:0 }}
```

But this doesn't work for me, and nothing appear in browser, then I changed my code as:

```
{{99.9| number:0  | currency }}
```

Now I get result but it isn't my expectation: ***$100.00***.

because I know that `number:0` must give me result as: ***$100***.

I want to know what is a difference between succession of parameters on filtering?

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters are applied to an expression serially the way they are used and separated by pipe `|`.

```
{{ 99.9 | currency | number:0 }}
```

Above applies, currency filter on `99.9` and then applies `number` filter with a 0 precision. As currency filter modifies `99.9` to $99.90, number filter cannot understand that and would fail to apply the filter.

On the other hand,

```
{{ 99.9 | number:0 | currency }} --> $100.00
```

using above, number filter rounds number `99.9` to `100` and then the currency filter is applied to see `$100.00` in the end.

What you ultimately need would be

```
{{ 99.9 | number:1 | currency }} --> $99.90
```

if you want to maintain the precision.

Read more about different types of [in-bult filters](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ng/filter).

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/noRfSJVNXQWTdkAGgLmZ?p=preview). Hope that it will help you to understand

Comment: Ah you want it without the cents. The angular's built in `currency` filter always adds cents. Create your own filter without cents, get inspired from the original one - function `currencyFilter` in the angular's [source](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.js). Have a look at the last parameter in return line, it is `2` - the `fractionSize`